# vs2013: static member does not link

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-studio-2013, state-pattern

I'm trying to write a simple FSM for one project that I'm working on. I got the GoF State sample from this [link](http://codewrangler.home.comcast.net/~codewrangler/tech_info/patterns_code.html#State) but it seems to be already bugged - when I try to build it into vs2013 I got the following error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Poco-stateMachine, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>Server.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class OffState & __cdecl OffState::theOffState(void)" (?theOffState@OffState@@SAAAV1@XZ)
1>C:\Users\Woody\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Poco-tcpServer4\Release\Poco-stateMachine.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

The only point where the "OffState::theOffState" is used is not a function call - its a ref to one singleton declared inside a class.

> Vehicle::Vehicle () :
>       mState(&OffState::theOffState()) { }

I got one huge headache trying to figure it out and still nothing.
Any idea?

The FSM Sample Code:

```
>   class Vehicle {   
>   public:
>      Vehicle ();
>   // whatever other ctors are needed
>      void turnOn(); // { mState->turnOn(*this); }
>      void engageGear(); // { mState->engageGear (*this); }
>      void disengageGear(); //{ mState->disengageGear (*this); }
>      void turnOff(); //{ mState->turnOff (*this); }
>   // other operations
>   private:
>      friend class VehState;
>      void changeState (VehState* newState); // { mState = newState; }
>   private:
>      VehState* mState;
>   };
> 
>   class VehState {
>   public:
>      virtual void turnOn(Vehicle&); // allows changing Vehicle object state pointer
>      virtual void engageGear(Vehicle&); // same as above
> 
>      virtual void disengageGear(Vehicle&);
>      virtual void turnOff(Vehicle&);
>   protected:
>      void changeState (Vehicle& veh, VehState* newState) { veh.changeState(newState); }
>   };
> 
>   class MovingState : public VehState {
>   public:
>      static MovingState& theMovingState(); // Singleton design pattern
>      virtual void disengageGear(Vehicle& veh);
>   };
> 
>   class IdleState : public VehState {
>   public:
>      static IdleState& theIdleState(); // Singleton design pattern
>      virtual void engageGear(Vehicle& veh) {changeState(veh, &MovingState::theMovingState()); }
>   };
> 
>   class OffState : public VehState {
>   public:
>      static OffState& theOffState(); // Singleton design pattern
>      virtual void turnOn(Vehicle& veh) { changeState(veh, &IdleState::theIdleState()); }
>   };
>   
>   // implement default behavior in VehState method implementations
>   // implementations of Vehicle methods:
>   Vehicle::Vehicle () :
>      mState(&OffState::theOffState()) {}
>   
>   void Vehicle::turnOn()        {        mState->turnOn(*this);   }   
>   void Vehicle::engageGear()    {        mState->engageGear (*this);   }   
>   void Vehicle::disengageGear() {        mState->disengageGear (*this);   }
>   void Vehicle::turnOff()       {        mState->turnOff (*this);   }
>
>   void Vehicle::changeState (VehState* newState) {
>      mState = newState;
>   }
>
```

Comment: `The only point where the "OffState::theOffState" is used` Show us this code part. And what is it really?

Comment: I did updated the question. It initialize the state value - just that (AFAIK)

Comment: Again, what types are theOffState and  mState? Show the definitions.

Comment: `The only point where the "OffState::theOffState" is used is not a function call - its a ref to one singleton declared inside a class.` But `static OffState& theOffState();` is indeed a function with a reference return type and not a reference itself.

Comment: Yup, I only saw that after VolAnd answer - I tought the singleton were complete but it was not - it was missing the function body. Thank you @deviantfan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unresolved symbol` means that your code has declaration, but doesn't have definition for `theOffState`. I think code example, you are trying to conpile, is not completed.

I guess the author of [Design Patterns Overview](http://codewrangler.home.comcast.net/~codewrangler/tech_info/patterns_code.html#State) hints at something by comment line “// Singleton design pattern”, as well as by line "// implement default behavior in VehState method implementations" in the example for State pattern

**EDIT:**

I have added some code, just to make it compilable (but you should think over logic and continue coding):

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Vehicle {
  public:
    Vehicle ();
    // whatever other ctors are needed
    void turnOn(); // { mState->turnOn(*this); }
    void engageGear(); // { mState->engageGear (*this); }
    void disengageGear(); //{ mState->disengageGear (*this); }
    void turnOff(); //{ mState->turnOff (*this); }
    // other operations
  private:
    friend class VehState;
    void changeState (VehState* newState); // { mState = newState; }
  private:
    VehState* mState;
  };

  class VehState {
  public:
    virtual void turnOn(Vehicle&); // allows changing Vehicle object state pointer
    virtual void engageGear(Vehicle&); // same as above

    virtual void disengageGear(Vehicle&);
    virtual void turnOff(Vehicle&);
  protected:
    void changeState (Vehicle& veh, VehState* newState) { veh.changeState(newState); }
  };

  class MovingState : public VehState {
  public:
    static MovingState& theMovingState() // Singleton design pattern
    {
        static MovingState stateMoving;
        return stateMoving;
    }
    virtual void disengageGear(Vehicle& veh) {}
  };

  class IdleState : public VehState {
  public:
    static IdleState& theIdleState() // Singleton design pattern
    {
        static IdleState stateIdle;
        return stateIdle;
    }
    virtual void engageGear(Vehicle& veh) {changeState(veh, &MovingState::theMovingState()); }
  };

  class OffState : public VehState {
  public:
    static OffState& theOffState() // Singleton design pattern
    {
        static OffState stateOff;
        return stateOff;
    }
    virtual void turnOn(Vehicle& veh) { changeState(veh, &IdleState::theIdleState()); }
  };

  // implement default behavior in VehState method implementations
  void VehState::turnOn(Vehicle& obj) {
    obj.turnOn();
  }
  void VehState::engageGear(Vehicle& obj) {
    obj.engageGear();
  }
  void VehState::disengageGear(Vehicle& obj) {
    obj.disengageGear();
  }
  void VehState::turnOff(Vehicle& obj) {
    obj.turnOff();
  }
  // implementations of Vehicle methods:

  Vehicle::Vehicle () :
    mState(&OffState::theOffState()) { }
  void Vehicle::turnOn() {
    mState->turnOn(*this);
  }
  void Vehicle::engageGear() {
    mState->engageGear (*this);
  }
  void Vehicle::disengageGear() {
    mState->disengageGear (*this);
  }
  void Vehicle::turnOff() {
    mState->turnOff (*this);
  }
  void Vehicle::changeState (VehState* newState) {
    mState = newState;
  }

int main()
{

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think he is pointing the use of the singleton (simplest implementation, not thread safe). I saw this same singleton construction into his page (same link). Anyway the other references are being resolved by the linker without problems.

Comment: I'm not sure about "other references are being resolved", perhaps other methods are not called, so you have no chance to see linkage problems

Comment: Look at class `OffState` that is derived from `VehState`, but doesn't implement some methods.... Will it work?

Comment: Me neither. The IdleState class, method engageGear, is using one similar construction - changeState(veh, &MovingState::theMovingState(). I dunno why the compiler is not complaining about this reference - and the others too. I'm really curios about what is happening here ...

Comment: I added some code into the VehState class methods but it didn't made any difference. I think that without this default code it would crash at run time but it would not affect the linker - I suppose.

Comment: "why the compiler is not complaining about this reference?" - because compiler doesn't see problems, but linker sees them, and linker says

Comment: thank you man! Now it made sense and you were right, the singleton was incomplete - that's why the linker was complaining about a function call.